# Why does my browser resolve DNS differently from dig?

Tags: dns, dig

I have recently set up Heroku hosting with a domain name.

I am able to visit `myappname.herokuapp.com`.

When I type `dig mydomain.com`, I see the first record (which I pointed my CNAME to) is `myappname.herokuapp.com`.

When I go to whatismydns.net, I can see `myappname.herokuapp.com` is the CNAME for `mydomain.com`.

**Why do I get something different from Heroku when I go to `myappname.herokuapp.com` versus `mydomain.com`?** (specifically, `mydomain.com` shows "There's nothing here, yet.").

Comment: 1) Always use dig with `@` to specify which nameservers you query. 2) Recent versions of some browsers (Firefox) if not configured outside of default will use DNS over HTTPS and query CloudFlare DNS server at 1.1.1.1 and not your OS level specified resolver, hence the result may be different.

Answer (score 1):

You may see something different from Heroku when you go to `myappname.herokuapp.com` versus `mydomain.com`, but that does not mean that your browser resolves differently from dig.

Since `CNAME` is configured, both `myappname.herokuapp.com` and `mydomain.com` will resolve to same ip address/server, but there is more to http request than ip address. That one remote heroku server hosts many websites (on a single ip address) and when it receives http request, it will use the value of "Host" http header to determine which website to serve (the value of that header is the hostname that you typed in your browser's address bar). .

My guess is that you did not [add a custom domain to your heroku app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains), so heroku server just does not know what to do with it, so it is serving the default page.